# How to set up Android for React-Native without Android Studio but only using the SDK tools?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, react-native, environment-variables

I've read pretty much read every article from google search, watched all the YouTube tutorials and checked out all the StackOverflow questions relating to this but cannot find my answer.

The official (but outdated) docs is not all that useful at all. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html 
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/getting-started.html

I am using Windows 10.

So far I have,

---

**User Variables**:

PATH 
`C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools` 
`C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

---

**System Variables**:

ANDROID_HOME 
`C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

ANDROID_SDK_HOME 
`C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

JAVA_HOME 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`

PATH 
`C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools` 
`C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

---

My git bash just keeps showing

> bash: android: command not found

And if I try to type in `android.bat`, it returns

> The "android" command is deprecated. 
>   For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio. 
>   For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat 
>   and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

And then if I try to type in `sdkmanager.bat`, I get

> bash: sdkmanager.bat: command not found

**EDIT**: 
I found out about the official SDK Manager installer made by Google Inc. and now my folder `C:\Users\RickyDam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk` looks like this

[image: screenshot of android-sdk folder]

But I still get

> android: command not found

even though my environment variables seem to all be in place...

Comment: You also need gradle, platform-tools which contain adb , if adb is not installed then react-native project will not run. You can install sdk using android studio and then uninstall android studio.

Comment: @ParasWatts Turns out there is an installer just for the SDK tools after all. And it's made by Google too, so it's official! http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/ although now i'm battling the issue of `android: command not found` again

Comment: I have android studio installed, but android.bat is not working. Sdkmanager.bat is working fine. Maybe there is problem with your sdkmanager.bat path. Maybe You should set it to bin \tools\bin .

Comment: Did it work or you find any other solution ?

Comment: Well for me `sdkmanager.bat` crashes if I double click it and running `sdkmanager.bat` in the terminal still doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Windows 10**

1. Install `Java SE Development Kit 8` 
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Install `Android SDK Manager`
   http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/
3. Install the options that are already selected when you open the `SDK Manager`
   • `Android SDK Tools` 
   • `Android SDK Platform-tools` 
   • `Android SDK Build-tools` 
   • `Android 8.0.0 (API 26)` 
   • `Extras > Google USB Driver`
4. Navigate to `Control Panel \ System and Security \ System \ Advanced System Settings \ Environment Variables`
5. For `User Variables` select `Path` and click `Edit...`.
6. Click `New` and add these: 
   • `C:\Users\`**`PC-NAME`**`\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools` 
   • `C:\Users\`**`PC-NAME`**`\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` 
   • `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144`

Now to confirm that it works, open `cmd` and type in `android`, the Android SDK Manager should open up.

**NOTE**: I suggest using the `default command prompt` over a third party one such as `Git Bash`. With `cmd`, when you run commands such as `npm install`, you actually get a loading bar where as in `Git bash`, you don't get one. Some commands that work properly in `cmd` such as `android` will not be recognized by `Git bash`.

7. Now in the command prompt, `cd` to the Desktop.
8. Run these commands: 
   • `npm install -g create-react-native-app` 
   • `create-react-native-app my-app` 
   • `cd my-app/` 
   • `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

**Mac Users**

Assuming you already have:

1. Java JDK 8
2. nodejs and react-native cli

Now let's download only command line tools (which is bottom of ) [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Follow these steps wisely:

> 1. unzip the folder in /opt/andriod directory
> 2. export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android
> 3. echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android" >> ~/.bashrc
> 4. /opt/android/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-23" "build-tools;23.0.1" "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23"

*You are all done.Congrats! if you made it all.Now from RN proj. folder run:*

```
react-native run-android
```