# React native Android NDK missing error?

Tags: android, react-native

I have setup basic react native android project. when i use react native cmd line to run the android project it gives me below error:
[image]

I have set my system variables for android and java properly. but still its asking NDK to be installed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know you've set the system variables for android and java properly if it doesn't work? 
Has it ever built on this computer before?

Are you sure NDK is the problem? 
The part that says `What went wrong` seems to show that you are lacking admin rights. 
Have you tried running CMD as admin?

[react-native run-android Building Error ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222227/react-native-run-android-building-error-appgeneratedebugbuildconfig) 
This fellow StackOverflow user also came across this problem and fixed it by properly initializing his `Path` variable.

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1813 
This github react-native community issue addresses a similar problem and a user commented:

> Fixed it by running `npm start -- --reset-cache` (after following the [Android Installation guide](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#android) ) on react-native 0.50.3

[How to set up Android for React-Native without Android Studio but only using the SDK tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626310/how-to-set-up-android-for-react-native-without-android-studio-but-only-using-the/45937963#45937963) 
I've previously answered my own question on initializing Windows environment variables for Android. Please take a look and tell me if that is how your system is set up.

Comment: i have deleted and recreated project and set env variables again and it worked. i think it is the system variables location it was sdk/tools intead of sdk/platform-tools